Formatting a read-only drive
My HP pen drive was once used in crypto mining somewhere (I don't know how). I want to format it to regain space because copying is not allowed in this drive, but I can't do that because it is read-only/locked. Please help me to format this drive.
GParted:


You can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution.

A USB stick that switches to read-only mode is often a sign of impending failure. If the budget allows it, you may want to pick up a new memory stick.

Does this answer your question? Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted

I agree with @matigo It seems to be a 32Gb stick. If it does not work straight from formatting break it in too and get a new one
